# How can ant pickup java result and use as property value?

Tags: java, ant

I search many places still not able to find what I am looking for. not sure if this is possible or not. While ant script is running the java code, the result should stay alive in jvm so how can I print it out at ant script side and not from java?? because I want to use the result again at my other part of ant script.

say, I after java method and I have

```
String result= "appleResultString";
return result;
```

Is there a way in ant script can pick up the the result while in the same jvm

```
<target name="test">
    <java classname="mytest" fork="true" >
    <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    <property="eat" value=${result}>
    </java>

<jmeter jmeterhome="homepath"
        testplan="name.jmx"
        resultlog="name.html">
  <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=pathToKey/>
  <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword= ${eat}/>
</jmeter>

    </target>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting the result as a System property using System.setProperty()?

Comment: I tried but maybe because in ant I also want to use the value in jmeter like <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${result}"/> but doesn't work.

Comment: How about using a temporary file ?

Comment: Don't think I will use temporary file, beause it will be the same as write out my password in a file. so still searching for a way to do it.

Comment: if you print the value, you could use outputproperty.

Comment: but if print value, it will be in the server system log. I have a "return" How can I get the value from there? I tried outputproperty but it doesn't pick up.

Comment: Sorry didn't make it clear that I use "return". I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a system property in your Java program, and Ant will capture it, but you must make sure you don't *fork* your `<java>` task.

Another possibility is to output the value, and capture that value in the `outputproperty` parameter of the `<java>` task. You already stated you can't use the return value.

Comment: I think I will use system property in java but how do I get the value from ant? In Java, I have System.setProperty("out", pwd); In Ant, How do I do <sysproperty key="pwd" value="out"/>? How to pass it into <jvmarg value="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${pwd}"/>??

Comment: If it's a Java property, it should be available to Ant as if you've set the Ant property via `<property name="..." value="..."/>`. Just don't fork the task.

Comment: but I am using the property that I set from java. so if I use <property name="..." value="..."/> I am setting a new property isn't it?? even when I do name = "test" value =${pwd} and echo ${test}. it still doesn't work.

Comment: Default Ant doesn't allow the resetting of properties. If a property is already set, `<property/>` will do nothing. If you set a property in Java, it will be set in Ant as long as you didn't fork the `<java/>` call.

Comment: I tried to set property in Java with  Property prop = new Property(); prop.setValue(pwd); and Properties capitals = new Properties(); capitals.put("Illinois", "Springfield"); in Ant I did <echoproperties/> but none of the properity show up. what I did wrong?

Comment: Are you using [getProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) and [setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) methods from [java.lang.System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)? That's what Ant uses to [set and get properties](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/property/GetProperty.java?revision=675996&view=markup).

Comment: Yes I am using java.lang.System. When I use System.setProperty("out", pwd); I am able to get property value in java. But it does not show up in Ant <echoproperties/>

Comment: Any idea how can I get the value in Ant? is it with java something like <java resultproperty="${out} clonevm="true">... or <property="test" value "{out}"/> ?? because I have tried above two ways and still not able to get the property value that I set with my java class.

Comment: I repost a new question for this issue. because @David W. did answer this question. The new post is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477880/how-can-ant-get-the-value-from-custom-java-system-property