# How can Ant get the value from custom Java system property

Tags: java, ant

In my java class I have

```
System.setProperty("test", drinks);
```

In my Ant build file I am able to execute the jave class.
How can I use the name "test" to get the result ${drinks} in Ant ??

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is possible is if you use the attribute *fork="false"* (false being the default value) in the [java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) Ant task. That is, if your Java program is executed in the same JVM as Ant. Otherwise, your Java program will be executed in a separate process and none of the system properties it sets will vbe accessible to Ant. Beware, though, that executing a non-forked Java program may (and often will) have undesired side effects on the rest of the Ant build.

Comment: Thanks, but I still want to try it out. My question right now is not able to see the value with <echo> in Ant. <echoproperties/> also doesn't show it. Could you give me an example on how to get the java system property value with Ant.

Answer (score 0):

If the property is set at the command line e.g. `ant -Dtest=drinks` it will be available from the build system as `${test}`, however if you're calling this property by means of executing Java code, you will need to find a way to get the value out from the spawned Java process into a new variable, usually using a combination of `System.out.println(...)` and `<exec ...>` tasks's [`outputproperty`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) and parsing as needed.